# How do I check the original value in label formatter using plottable.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plottable

I have a relatively simple bar chart using Plottable.  All the bars start at 0 but the third bar can be negative and changes colors.  To display in this way, for the third bar I use `Math.abs(value)`.  The problem is when it is negative I need to have the label actually display that it is negative as well.  How would I set the label to display a negative number properly here but keeping the same format of the graph?

**note:** The script can be run a few times to see both the positive and negative versions of the profit bar.

```js
function HBarChart(key, state) {
  var colors = {
    Sales: '#00c786',
    Expenses: '#f5a623',
    Profit: '#009464',
    Profit_neg: '#ea655d'
  };

  this._eleSelector = 'svg#' + key;
  this.xScale = new Plottable.Scales.Linear().domainMin(0);
  this.yScale = new Plottable.Scales.Category();
  this.xAxis = new Plottable.Axes.Numeric(this.xScale, 'bottom');
  this.yAxis = new Plottable.Axes.Category(this.yScale, 'left')
    .innerTickLength(0)
    .endTickLength(0);
  
  this.plot = new Plottable.Plots.Bar('horizontal')
    .x(function(d) {
      return Math.abs(d.x);
    }, this.xScale)
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.category;
    }, this.yScale)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return colors[d.category + (d.x < 0 ? '_neg' : '')];
    })
    .labelFormatter(function(d) {
      return Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
      }).format(d);
    })
    .labelsEnabled(true);
  
  this.setData(state);
  this.chart = new Plottable.Components.Table([
    [this.yAxis, this.plot]
  ]);
  
  this.chart.renderTo(this._eleSelector);
}

HBarChart.prototype.setData = function(state) {
  var dummySet = {
    revenue: Math.random() * 10000 + 1000,
    expense: Math.random() * 10000 + 1000
  };
  
  dummySet.profit = dummySet.revenue - dummySet.expense;
  
  var dataSet = [{
    category: 'Sales',
    x: dummySet.revenue
  }, {
    category: 'Expenses',
    x: dummySet.expense
  }, {
    category: 'Profit',
    x: dummySet.profit
  }];
  if (this.dataset) {
    this.plot.removeDataset(this.dataset);
  }
  
  this.dataset = new Plottable.Dataset(dataSet);
  this.plot.addDataset(this.dataset);

}

new HBarChart('test');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/2.0.0/plottable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/2.0.0/plottable.min.js"></script>

<svg id="test"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `xScale.scale` function to calculate te range value from an absolute domain value:

```
  var origXScale = this.xScale.scale.bind(this.xScale);
  this.xScale.scale = function(d) { 
    return origXScale(Math.abs(d)); 
  };
```

and let the x accessor return original values:

```
 this.plot = new Plottable.Plots.Bar('horizontal')
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }, this.xScale)
```

This way your formatter will also get the original values.

Full example:

```js
function HBarChart(key, state) {
  var colors = {
    Sales: '#00c786',
    Expenses: '#f5a623',
    Profit: '#009464',
    Profit_neg: '#ea655d'
  };

  this._eleSelector = 'svg#' + key;
  this.xScale = new Plottable.Scales.Linear().domainMin(0);
  var origXScale = this.xScale.scale.bind(this.xScale);
  this.xScale.scale = function(d) { 
       return origXScale(Math.abs(d)); 
  };
  this.yScale = new Plottable.Scales.Category();
  this.xAxis = new Plottable.Axes.Numeric(this.xScale, 'bottom');
  this.yAxis = new Plottable.Axes.Category(this.yScale, 'left')
    .innerTickLength(0)
    .endTickLength(0);
  
  this.plot = new Plottable.Plots.Bar('horizontal')
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }, this.xScale)
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.category;
    }, this.yScale)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return colors[d.category + (d.x < 0 ? '_neg' : '')];
    })
    .labelFormatter(function(d) {
      return Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
      }).format(d);
    })
    .labelsEnabled(true);
  
  this.setData(state);
  this.chart = new Plottable.Components.Table([
    [this.yAxis, this.plot]
  ]);
  
  this.chart.renderTo(this._eleSelector);
}

HBarChart.prototype.setData = function(state) {
  var dummySet = {
    revenue: Math.random() * 10000 + 1000,
    expense: Math.random() * 10000 + 1000
  };
  
  dummySet.profit = dummySet.revenue - dummySet.expense;
  
  var dataSet = [{
    category: 'Sales',
    x: dummySet.revenue
  }, {
    category: 'Expenses',
    x: dummySet.expense
  }, {
    category: 'Profit',
    x: dummySet.profit
  }];
  if (this.dataset) {
    this.plot.removeDataset(this.dataset);
  }
  
  this.dataset = new Plottable.Dataset(dataSet);
  this.plot.addDataset(this.dataset);

}

new HBarChart('test');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/2.0.0/plottable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/2.0.0/plottable.min.js"></script>

<svg id="test"></svg>
```